# SQL switching values on a column

Tags: mysql

In interviews for software developer roles SQL questions can sometimes come up. There is a classic question around switching values in a column, typically swapping the gender of people in a table for example:

```
id   name   sex   salary
------------------------
0    Tom    f     45000
1    Jane   m     22000
```

the typical question asks you to do this in one statement (and the answer is here: Switching values in a column with one update statement)

However my question is NOT that.

My question is what is the naive approach, that is, how I can temporarily store the values. In fact I'd like to do this two ways: 1. In a temporary column (that does not persist after the statement) and 2. In a temporary variable.

Comment: Are there only 2 rows?

Comment: It's an example, rather that a real table. So n rows.

Comment: If N rows, swap just in rows 0 and 1?  Or in pairs?  If so, what defines a 'pair'?  That's just the beginning of my questions to point out how imprecisely phrased the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Odd question with terms like temporary storage. General SQL is denormalized so fetching when need rather than a transform.

Question 1: results and be an expression like:

```
SELECT id, sex, IF(sex='m', 'f', 'm') as antisex FROM table
```

Question 2: A variable can contain only a single value. So from [ref manual on SELECT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT id, sex, IF(sex='m', 'f', 'm') INTO @id, @sex, @antisex FROM table LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, apologies but as explained I'm learning SQL as it comes up in other interviews rather than being any sort of expert.

Answer (score 1):

The common update variant uses 2 copies of a table - one is a data source and another is new values acceptor.

```
UPDATE table t_src, table t_dst
SET t_dst.field_dst = t_src.field_src
WHERE (compilance conditions)
```

For the task above (switch sex for the records with IDs 0 and 1) it can be

```
UPDATE table t_src, table t_dst
SET t_dst.sex = t_src.sex
WHERE (t_src.id, t_dst.id) IN ((0,1), (1,0))
```

And no "temporarily store the values" needed.